# How to create a redirect for an incoming url string in .net

Tags: asp.net

I have a vendor that has recently created a batch of wallet cards with the wrong url and I would like to create a .net page that would redirect the user to the correct web page.

The current URL is similar to the following
http://xx.xxxxxx.xxx/xxx/12345.jpg

The current url needs to re-formated to the following
http://zzzzz.zzzzzzzzz.zzz/12345.jpg

I am not that experienced in .net so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do realize the URL you use is an image and thus wouldn't be processed as an ASP.Net request right?

Comment: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-request-filtering-and-url-rewriting would be the IIS URL rewrite that may work as you need though this is separate from ASP.Net.

Comment: It's not very clear what exactly you are trying to do here. You said you want to create a .net page that will redirect, so are you saying that the .net page will have these bunch of links and when you click on that link, they should be redirected to a separate link? Or are you trying to say that your problem URL is part of .net application and you want automatic redirection? The answer will differ based on what you are trying to do. In the first case, you just write string replacement logic, OR maintain a mapping URL set and in second case, you will have to do some url rewriting.

Comment: The URL that is incoming will be like http://xx.xxxxxx.xxx/xxx/12345.jpg and I need to reformat the URL http://zzzzz.zzzzzzzzz.zzz/12345.jpg and send the user browser to http://zzzzz.zzzzzzzzz.zzz/12345.jpg

Comment: First you have to instruct the asp.net pipeline that you want to process incoming request for static files. By default, static files are not handled by .net. You may also want to look into creating a http handler with an .ashx extension.